# Action after recursion is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I wrote a function which goes through directories and analyzes files in it but I don't know how to detect that the whole process is done (that it analyzed all files in all directories and sub directories) so I can do something with the result then.

I used recursion but I'm still learning it and I know it isn't quite right so I would like to ask for help.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');

let result = {};

const goThroughDirs = parentPath => {
    const stat = fs.statSync(parentPath);

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        _.each(fs.readdirSync(parentPath), child => goThroughDirs(path.join(parentPath, child)));
    } else {
        analyseFile(parentPath)
            .then(response => {
                result = _.merge({}, result, response);
            });
    }
};

goThroughDirs(path.join(__dirname, 'rootDir'));
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are already using promises, it's as simple as

```
function goThroughDirs(parentPath) {
    const stat = fs.statSync(parentPath);

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        return Promise.all(_.map(fs.readdirSync(parentPath), child =>
//      ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^
            goThroughDirs(path.join(parentPath, child))
        )).then(responses =>
            _.merge({}, ...responses);
        );
    } else {
        return analyseFile(parentPath);
//      ^^^^^^
    }
}

goThroughDirs(path.join(__dirname, 'rootDir')).then(result => {
    // it's done
    console.log(results);
});
```